# Filter log by matching pattern - log4j

Tags: log4j, pattern-matching

I have the following layout patter in my log4j xml file:

`"%d{ISO8601} %c %p [%t] [%x] 9.5.4.RC12 %m%n"`

What I want is that when ever I get a log containing message `process [proc#] completed`, it should be skipped. I mean every log except the one containing this message should be printed. `[proc#]` will contain the process number of max lenght 4.
What can I desing a filter with this function in my xml config file. If so, then how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ExpressionFilter can do that.

In a filter definition inside an appender definition, use an expression similar to (note LIKE is the regex match operator):

"MSG LIKE 'process \[.*\] completed'"

See ExpressionFilter javadoc here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/filter/ExpressionFilter.html

**Example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="CONSOLE">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout>
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
            <param name="expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= com.company.BackendNotAvailableException" />
            <param name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value ="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Example taken from here: http://blog.trifork.com/2011/08/23/filtering-specific-exceptions-when-using-log4j/

Comment: What does the `~=` operator do?`

Comment: It's a case-insensitive partial-text match.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list of all operators and their meanings somewhere?

Comment: Under the help menu there is a tutorial - the tutorial lists all of the operators.

Comment: Which help menu? Context?

Comment: If you are using the 'developer snapshot' available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy - when you run the app, the actual top level Help menu in the menu bar has a Tutorial option.

Comment: Pedant: the `~=` operator should really be `≅`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've configured log4j to filter out by IP address. In particular `127.0.0.1` as illustrated in `log4j.xml` below. Note, you must also include `log4j.dtd` alongside `log4j.xml`. You must use the XML syntax.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CATALINA" 
            class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/catalina" />
        <layout class="net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="CATALINAOUT" 
            class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>


        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
            <param name="expression" value="MSG LIKE '127.0.0.1'" />
            <param name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
        </filter>


    </appender>
    <appender name="LOCALHOST" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/localhost" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="LOCALHOST" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CATALINA" />
        <appender-ref ref="CATALINAOUT" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: There is a handy tool that can convert `log4j.properties` to `log4j.xml`. I used it to generate everything but the `<filter>` element. https://github.com/jroyals/log4j-properties-converter