# How to append hostname to log file in log4j.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logfile

I want to append hostname and date to log file name.So log file Name should be like **app_hostname.date.log**.
**Note:** This should run in both **linux and windows.**

```
<appender name="applog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${path}/app.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value=".dd-MM-yyyy" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
</appender>
```

And how to add filter based on the log pattern, not as `StringMatchFilter`.I want pattern to be matched.
Thanks in advance

Comment: consider using `logback` or `log4j2`. start wtih logback's `SiftingAppender`

Comment: @Nati,Please be more specific..If possible with code snippet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do this first from your java code** *then* **configure log4j** into application,

**NOTE : handle or catch required Exception while below code execute.**

```
// step-1 : set hostName into System's property, which will use by log4j
System.setProperty("hostName", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()); 
//step - 2 : set currentDate into System's property, which will use by log4j
System.setProperty("currentDate", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
//step - 3 : now configure/load log4j into Application , if it's not still loaded earlier then.
org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(YourJavaClassName.class); // ALERT : before this step above 2-step must needs to be execute, otherwise file-name won't appear as you required.

//LOG.debug("anything whatever programmer what to log");
```

**UPDATED :**

If your application is web-application, 
then need to configure property which we want here after`tomcat-server` start and before any `application` run,

for that create one class `ApplicationConfiguration`  which has `ServletContextListener` interface implemented which helps here to run first before any application runs.

*do likewise,*

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ApplicationConfiguration implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        try {
            // step-1 : set hostName into System's property, which will use by log4j
            System.setProperty("hostName", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            //step - 2 : set currentDate into System's property, which will use by log4j
            System.setProperty("currentDate", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    }


}
```

......

***Set your log4j.xml file likewise,***

```
<appender name="applog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${path}/app_${hostName}.${currentDate}.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value=".dd-MM-yyyy" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
</appender>
```

please, update web.xml file accordingly,

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.pck1.ApplicationConfiguration
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

> This configuration need to apply into `web.xml` because application
>   when start, by this configuration it will follow it like
>   Context-listener.

---

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<logger name="packageName.AAA" additivity="false" >
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="applog"/>
 </logger>
```

Comment: actually log4j getting called when the application starts.

Comment: @Sam your application is web-application ?

Comment: Yes it is a web app...tomcat is app server

Comment: @Sam refer my 'UPDATED' section

Comment: @Sam once class ApplicationConfiguration(what i suggest) created then no need to put above mentioned 2-steps for set hostname and currentDate because it's handled by ApplicationConfiguration - class itself.

Comment: @Sam my suggested answer, works or not ? do i need to provide more information to make you success. let me know

Comment: @Vishal..Thank you for your efforts..but its not worked..Do i need to add this in web.xml or something?

Comment: @Sam no no it's works on my machine, something went wrong please check and follow as i suggest..

Comment: "LogName_." this is what am getting...Actually i placed a breakpoint in that class and started tomcat but it's not at all came to that place.

Comment: "LogName_" log file name ?

Comment: I Mean values are not replacing...Empty value for hostname because control is not going to that class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107556/discussion-between-vishal-gajera-and-sam).

Comment: @Sam please see my update answer which include update into web.xml file

Comment: Wow! done...answer for one more..get bounty...I am logging two logs from same package..but particularly from one class I want to write for seperate log..how to have filter for that one

Comment: @Sam please post another question.

Comment: Actually i have asked that in this one only

Comment: @Sam okay, let me check. because this thing wasn't in my mind

Comment: @Sam what is name for second class's log-file ?

Comment: 1st one package..second one AAA

Comment: @Sam can you please check my UPDATE 2 section .

Comment: <logger name="a.b.c(package)">
  <priority value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="file1" />
 </logger> 
 
 <logger name="class(a.b.c.class)">
  <level value="info" />
  <appender-ref ref="file2" />
 </logger>

Comment: Both should be independent

Comment: No..if i try to write for a.b.c.class its writing to file1 also...that should not happen

Comment: How can I Differ that??

Comment: by putting 2-logger for 2-appender with proper 'ref' pass.

Comment: filter has not solved..but still m giving bounty for your efforts..thank you...if you come to know please update the answer

Answer (score 10):

Following the log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) you can do environment variable lookups, so in Unix-like systems this should work:

```
<Property name="MYHOST">${env:HOSTNAME}</Property>
<Appenders>
  <File name="File1" fileName="${MYHOST}_file.log">
  ...
  </File>
</Appenders>
```

Beware that $HOSTNAME is not always available by default and you might need to export it explicitly in the shell, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/132489/hostname-environment-variable-on-linux).

Comment: To update this answer, it is better to use {hostName} as it is always available by default unlike the suggested answer. From post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530672/how-to-add-hostname-for-my-log-file-in-log4j2-xml-i-am-working-on-spring-3-0-5

Answer (score 6):

I found that just `${hostName}` by default would work for latest **log4j**

Something like this:

```
    <File name="file" fileName="${baseDir}/${hostName}-file.log" append="true">
```

This is documented under here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration

In the **Default Properites** Section:

> The default map is pre-populated with a value for **"hostName"** that is the current system's host name or IP address

Answer (score 1):

Cf. this  [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6573221/4153864) to a similar question, the request wouldn't be obvious to satisfy, even if according to this mailing-list [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=log4j-dev@jakarta.apache.org&q=subject:%22Hostname%20support%20in%20PatternLayout%20%5C%28patch%20included%5C%29%22&o=newest), this is a long-standing request.

Using a recent version of log4j, the end of this documentation [section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) seems you already have the feature available using properties.

Anyway, you always have the solution to do it yourself with a specialized pattern layout, like [here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2011-06-07-username-in-log4j/).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for me main problem is I have two logs for the same package,but if it comes from my custom class it should write to one log, if it comes from other than that class it should write to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can defined a system property `hostname` and change the configuration:

```
<param name="File" value="${path}/app_${hostname}.log" />
```

Make sure the system property is set before log4j initialization.

For adding filter, please refer the answer of [Filter log by matching pattern - log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304628/filter-log-by-matching-pattern-log4j)

**UPDATED:**
A simple solution for writing different log:

```
<logger name="com"><!-- for Class Package is com.???... -->
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="applog" />
</logger>
<logger name="loggerForCustomClass">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="customlog" />
</logger>
```

Change code in your program:

```
//message will write to "customlog" appender
Logger.getLogger("loggerForCustomClass").info("log from custom class");

//message will write to "applog" appender
Logger.getLogger(getClass()).info("log from other class");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for me main problem is I have two logs for the same package,but if it comes from my custom class it should write to one log, if it comes from other than that class it should write to another.

Answer (score 1):

Following configuration will do the trick

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="C:\\Users\\kavurira\\Desktop\\log4j-${HostName}.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m${HostName}%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

Just set "HostName" as system property, before initialization of Log4j.

System.setProperty("HostName", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
```

Comment: where to set the hostname property, i dont have any servlet(load on start up)...?

Comment: No need of load on start up, there must be login or some starting of your project  right?                                                                                                                                                                 You have to set the property in your project, before executing the following line in your project                                                            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("classname")

Comment: I tried...but in my case log files are generating when the application starts..so its not taking the name

Comment: Let me know which application server are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Write you own custom appender extending the basic appenderws. This will help you to manipulate the properties in java.

See This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324075/1594992

Or Simply set the command line arguments & system property like this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953207/1594992

Comment: log4j will load on application start up,so how to define by system.setProperty

Comment: How do you call log4j , do you have a base class ? If so you can set the property there

Comment: Log4j is initializing on after spring boot.INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN

Answer (score 0):

try this : `"${env:HOST}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"` Hostname + Date . In `yaml`:

```
Properties:
    Property:
      - name: log-path
        value:  "logs"
      - name: filePattern
        value:  "${env:HOST}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"

  Appenders:

    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: "${log-path}/filelog-${filePattern}.log"
```