# How can i get port number on which my application is running in logging format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

How can I get host-name or post number under logging information? This didn't work:

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %d{localhost}  ---- %msg%n
```

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170962/how-to-append-hostname-to-log-file-in-log4j-xml). Did you check all the associated answers to see if they already answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to implement `ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent>` with your spring boot main class.
2. Embedded servlet container will provide you exact port number in which your application is initialize.
3. Host Address/Name can be fetched using innet address.
4. Replace System.out.println to logger.info()

For your reference :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringBootAppMain implements ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent> {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent embeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent) {
        System.out.println("Port " + embeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent.getApplicationContext().getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort());
        try {
            System.out.println("HOST Address " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("Host Name " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where we are using Environment environment?

Comment: @Khushi I didn't get you. FYI Environment is a interface in Spring and it holds property of  system & application i.e which profile,port & management port the  what is the configuration of vm and so on. We can conclude as it holds metric info.